# getting out of memory exception while using fileStream

Tags: asp.net, filestream, out-of-memory

I am facing an Issue while uploading file from a web page to server. It works fine for files upto 200 MB, but starts throwing out of memory exception.
Could you please help me
I have pasted the code below

```
private void UploadToServer(HttpPostedFile oHttpPostedFile)
    {
        string CalCheckSum = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string FileName = getFileName(oHttpPostedFile.FileName.Trim());
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("Upload") + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName)))
            {
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("Upload") + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName));
            }
            string serverFilePath = Server.MapPath("Upload") + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileName);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(serverFilePath, FileMode.CreateNew);
            string strFileFormName = serverFilePath;
           // Uri oUri = new Uri(strUrl);



            // DFB: Upload goes into stream
            Stream myStream = oHttpPostedFile.InputStream;
            string _name = oHttpPostedFile.FileName;
            string _contentType = oHttpPostedFile.ContentType;
            // DFB: Create buffer for stream
            Byte[] myBuffer;
            myBuffer = new byte[10240];
            if (myStream.Length == 0)
            {
                //Zero Bytes file Can not be processed
                CalCheckSum = string.Empty;
                return;
            }

            else if (myStream.Length > 10240)
                myBuffer = new byte[10240];
            else
                myBuffer = new byte[myStream.Length];
            StringBuilder filecontent = new StringBuilder();
            int fileLength = (int)myStream.Length;
            int length = (int)myStream.Length / myBuffer.Length + 1;
            int lastPacketLength = (int)myStream.Length % 10240;
            int count = 1;
            while (myStream.Read(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                if (count == length)
                    fs.Write(myBuffer, 0, lastPacketLength);
                else
                    fs.Write(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.Length);
                count++;
            }
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            myStream.Dispose();
            myBuffer = null;
            myStream = null;
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(serverFilePath);
            byte[] pbytCombinedArrays = new byte[fileLength];
            int numBytesToRead = fileLength;
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                int n = fileStream.Read(pbytCombinedArrays, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                if (n == 0)
                    break;
                numBytesRead += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }
            fileStream.Dispose();
            fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception? At `new byte[fileLength]`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes I am getting at the same place.

   FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(serverFilePath);
            byte[] pbytCombinedArrays = new byte[fileLength];

Comment: Do you need to read all the data into an array? In the code that you show you don't use it for anything. (Besides, you could use `byte[] pbytCombinedArrays = File.ReadAllBytes(serverFilePath);` instead of that last part of the code.)

Comment: I am using the array in later part of the code.
I tried `byte[] pbytCombinedArrays = File.ReadAllBytes(serverFilePath);`
I get the same error

Comment: How are you using that array? You get the error becase you are simply trying to allocate an array that is larger than the allowed memory space. Web applications are generally limited to about 300 MB.

Comment: Isn't there any work around for this?
I am using the array as below
`int numBytesToRead = fileLength;
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                numBytesToRead.
                int n = fileStream.Read(pbytCombinedArrays, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
               
                if (n == 0)
                    break;
                numBytesRead += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }
            fileStream.Dispose();
            fileStream.Close();`

Comment: That's the same code as in your question. Do you use the data from the file for anything once you have read it into the array?

Comment: I am using to calculate checksum.

`CalCheckSum = CheckSum.GetCrc(pbytCombinedArrays, CheckSum.CrcType.CRC16);`

Which calls below method
`public static string GetCrc(byte[] bytes, CrcType crcType)
        {
            string result;
                           case CrcType.CRC16:
                    result = GetCrc16(bytes);
            return result;
        }`

Comment: Calculate the checksum for the file stream directly, or by sending several smaller blocks of data into the algorithm.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate CRC 16 Checksum without using byte array??

Comment: You don't need all the data in a single array, you can read chunks from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because you are trying to allocate more memory than is allowed for the application. Web applications are generally limited to about 300 MB.

The solution would be to avoid reading the entire file into memory. It's simply too large for a web application to handle all at once.